# Data is extracted except for the link using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

All the data in class name is extracted except for the link.

```
url = 'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/la/cars?deliveryMethod=local_pick_up&itemCondition=used&exact=false'
driver.get(url)

from IPython.core.display import display,HTML

elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('kbiprv82')
for ele in elements:
    if 'Toyota' in ele.text:
        print(ele.text)
        print(ele.get_attribute('Href'))
```

Comment: Maybe href instead of Href?

Comment: its just the same

Comment: I've tried your link and am also not able to get the data. Selenium doesn't seem to get into the html code. Googling 'scraping facebook' gives a lot of information. Maybe you can find some hints.